# ToDataURL (JavaScript) of Canvas is Creating a Corrupt PNG File After Upload to Server Thru PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas, png

I tried to give a working example of my code on JSFiddle, but I could only get the dataURL of the image to go into an input. (JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dyt943s0/38/.) (EDIT: I was able to make a link that sends you to the DataURL image.)

Here is a copy of the corrupted image, (if you try opening in photoshop, it will not work, and gives the error: "Could not complete your request because the file-format module cannot parse the file"):

[image]
Or view http://mcgroup.freshfocuscrm.com/img/phot.png for a copy of the original photo.

Here is my JavaScript code (as it is on my actual web page):

```
var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="../../ffm.freshfocuscrm.com/Driving Log/tmp/background-lines.png";
function start(){

  var bottleCanvas = document.getElementById('bottleCanvas');
 // var designCanvas = $("#chartContainer .canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0);
  var ctxb=bottleCanvas.getContext('2d');
  //var ctxd=editorCanvas.getContext('2d');

  ctxb.drawImage(img,0,0);
  //ctxd.fillRect(5,5,5,5);

  downloadCanvas();
}

function downloadCanvas() {
  var bottleCanvas = document.getElementById('bottleCanvas');
  var designCanvas = $("#chartContainer .canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0);

  var bottleContext = bottleCanvas.getContext('2d');
  bottleContext.drawImage(designCanvas, 0, 0);

  var dataURL = bottleCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  console.log(dataURL);
  $(".dataurl").val(dataURL);
  $(".submit-create-pdf").click();


}
```

Then my PHP Code to download the image onto my server:

```
$img = $_POST['dataurl_image'];
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $fileData = base64_decode($img);
        //saving
        $fileName = 'photos.png';
        file_put_contents(WEBSITE_URL.'/Driving Log/tmp/'.$fileName, $fileData);
```

However, I am almost sure that this is due to a PHP error, since if I put the DataURL code directly into my URL bar, and save the image manually, I can open it in PhotoShop. I just can't seem to figure out what that error is.

Some additional info:

- The image seems to get created properly, for example, I can open it in Windows Photo Viewer and I can display it in an  tag on my site.
- If I open in MS Paint, and save the image, then the image becomes uncorrupted.
- I have also tried using the following PHP code to create the image, which does not work either:

  $image_url = $_POST['dataurl_image'];
          $image = @file_get_contents($image_url);
          $filename = 'uniqqid.png';
          file_put_contents(WEBSITE_URL.'/Driving Log/tmp/'.$filename, $image);
- The image was uncorrupted when I used the following JS code (instead of the one above):

  var canvas = $("#chartContainer .canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      console.log(dataURL);
      $("#btn-download").attr("href", dataURL);
      $(".dataurl").val(dataURL);

Also, please note: I am trying all of this code on my Localhost Wamp Server, if that makes a difference?

Thank you!

Comment: The file 1cqZq.png that you posted has been truncated.  It ends with a partially-complete IDAT chunk, and there's no IEND chunk.

Comment: Okay, sounds ugly. Do you think it is something to do with the way the PHP code is saving the toDataUrl code?

Comment: By the way, how did you know that part of the PNG was truncated?

Comment: I ran ImageMagick's "identify -verbose file.png" and also "pngcheck -v file.png".

Comment: "If I open in MS Paint, and save the image, then the image becomes uncorrupted" - not really. Applications are [allowed to handle errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#13Decoders.Errors) any way they see fit. That both includes failing to open the image (as Photoshop does) and continuing with partial data (MS Paint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by Google Chrome limiting the number of characters allowed inside of an input (type=text) tag. My DataURL code was close to 600,000 characters, but the input was cutting the code off at a number less than that, which caused my image to be corrupt.

To solve this, I went into my JS code and tried to shorten the DataURL code.

So, instead of:

`var dataURL = bottleCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

I used:

`var dataURL = bottleCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);`

And it shrunk the number of characters to less than 100,000.

This allowed the full DataURL code to get passed thru to my PHP server, which then allowed me to create an uncorrupted image.

Comment: Thank you @Kelsey. You saved my day :)